# How to Find Determinant of size $n \cdot n$ in infinite terms

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I tired to find a recurrence relation for the particular "Matrix" and also tried tricks with Co-factors, but am failing to find a simpler solution, one which does not involve heavy math on legranzhe or eigen-values

Comment: Guess a pattern by doing small examples, then prove it by doing row and column operations: start by adding columns 2,...,n to column 1. (Also, the entry in row 2 column 1 - are you sure that's right?)

Comment: What exactly are the elements in the first column? I am confused by the number $2$ there.

Comment: Seems like you’ve got a typo there. I suspect that the first element in the second row should be $1$. If so, this determinant is equal to the characteristic polynomial of a matrix with a simple structure for which the eigenvalues are easily determined without constructing this polynomial.

Comment: If, as suggested, the first element of the second row is $1$, then the eigenvalues of the matrix (without $\lambda$) are seen to be $0$ (multiplicity $n-1$) and $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ (multiplicity $1$).  From this we can reconstruct the characteristic polynomial as $\lambda^{n-1}(\lambda-\frac{n(n+1)}{2})$.

Comment: The problem has no writing mistakes double checked